# Shortcut key to shutdown PC in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, shutdown

What is the shortcut key to shutdown the computer for Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

### Safe(r) Shutdown:

To shut down from a terminal you can use `sudo shutdown`. If you want to make a shutdown shortcut you can assign the command `gksudo shutdown` to a shortcut.

There by default is no safe shutdown key combo in newer versions of ubuntu that I know of. In older versions of ubuntu using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> will give you an option to shutdown though.

### Force Shutdown:

If you want to force a mostly-safe shutdown you can use REISUB.

Hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>SYSREQ</kbd>. The <kbd>SYSREQ</kbd> key is the <kbd>PRT SCRN</kbd> (Print Screen) key on most systems. So hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>PRT SCRN</kbd>, then press the following keys in order:
<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>.

Be sure to wait at least 2 seconds after pressing one key before pressing the next! After you press <kbd>B</kbd>, the system should reboot.

For more info on <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SYSREQ</kbd> combos check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key